# How to get a wxlistbox's styles?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writting wxpython test for c++ wxwidgets app, I want to post event manually.
If a listbox support multiselect, UnselectAll()  is not needed when post a select event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetWindowStyleFlag` to get the style flag.

```
styleFlag =  self.listCtrl.GetWindowStyleFlag()
if styleFlag & wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL:
    printf "is single select"
else:
    printf "is multiple select"
```